# powershell newbie breaking a script with multiple functions

Tags: powershell

My powershell script has the following structure

```
[CmdletBinding()]param()
process{
# call function a
# call function b
}
end{}
Function a{
[CmdletBinding()]param()
process{}
}
Function b{
[CmdletBinding()]param()
process{}
}
```

The above structure throws an error telling me that

```
Unexpected token 'Function' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

This is my first powershell script

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: When you implement `Begin-Process-End` in a function, you can't place code *outside* of these three blocks. Put your inner functions inside the `begin` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your functions inside the `begin` or `Process` Sections

Execute your code inside the `Process` Section

Cleanup inside the `End` Section

See Examples:

```
[CmdletBinding()]param() ## BTW: You don't need this line if you are not using args

begin{

"Declare Functions in begin`n"
Function Get-Number{
"Number: " + (Get-Random)
}

Function Get-Time{
Get-Date
}

}

process{

"Execute Function in process"
Get-Number 
Get-Time

}
end{
"`nEnd of code"
}
```